# Mapping REST response in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I have the following `@list` received via MailChimp's API:

```
{"members"=>[{"email_address"=>"a@gmail.com"}, {"email_address"=>"b@gmail.com"}]}
```

And I'm trying to map it so that my `@list` is in the following format:

```
a@gmail.com, b@gmail.com, ...
```

However my attempts are unsuccessful with the following code in the controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.json  {render json: @list{|email| {:email_address => email.email_address} }}
    format.html
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list = {"members"=>[{"email_address"=>"a@gmail.com"}, {"email_address"=>"b@gmail.com"}]}
list['members'].map{|m| m['email_address']}
# => ["a@gmail.com", "b@gmail.com"]
```

so `render json: @list['members'].map{|m| m['email_address']}` will get what you want